# Find the values of x for which this series converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the values of x for which

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{x^n}$$
converges.

This is what I'm thinking:

I tried graphing it with a really big n number to get an idea on how it may look, and the graph shows nothing. Im completely stuck, am I not considering a theorem?

Comment: The introductory question is quite clear, but the ideas below are very hardly readable for me. The series converges if $|x|>2$.

Comment: Sorry I'll try and fix it I was but jammering about how many different things I tried and cannot get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{x^n} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^n$$

is a geometric series with initial term $2/x$ and common ratio $2/x$.

A geometric series with a non-zero initial term converges when the common ratio has absolute value less than $1$.

You could also apply the Ratio Test, which leads to the same result, although you have to check that the series diverges when $x = \pm 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1 : Look at $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{2}{x}) ^n$$

which is the same sum.

Hint 2 : The given series is a geometric series.

Comment: Ok, so I could say something like: Since this is a geometric series and r = 2/x. Then how would I determind if the absolute value or r is greater than or smaller than 1, since I dont have any x values? Or would the values be when x is negative, it would converge, and when its positive, it would diverge?

Comment: You have to solve the inequality $|\frac{2}{x}|<1$ because the quotient is $q=\frac{2}{x}$

Comment: Oh ok! So 2 < x , so any number greater than 2 will converge!

Comment: And we know that because since it is geometric r = 2/x and only series where r <= 1 converge, so we use 2/x as r! Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. And for $x<-2$, it also converges.